PHPStan: Doctrine Repository @method tags with no value type specified in iterable type array
After upgrading to phpstan-doctrine version 1.5.2 it is required to do the following changes:
diff --git a/src/Repository/TagRepository.php b/src/Repository/TagRepository.php
index 89bc22a..6f65925 100644
--- a/src/Repository/TagRepository.php
+++ b/src/Repository/TagRepository.php
@@ -12,9 +12,9 @@ use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
 /**
  * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<Tag>
  * @method Tag|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
- * @method Tag|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
+ * @method Tag|null findOneBy(array<mixed> $criteria, array<mixed> $orderBy = null)
  * @method array<Tag> findAll()
- * @method array<Tag> findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
+ * @method array<Tag> findBy(array<mixed> $criteria, array<mixed> $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
  */
 class TagRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
 {

My IDE (PhpStorm) is now interpreting the <mixed> after array in @method-tag parameters as an syntax error.
Is there another way to fix PHPStan errors like Class App\Repository\TagRepository has PHPDoc tag @method for method findBy() parameter #1  $criteria with no value type specified in iterable type array?

Looks like a related PhpStorm ticket to me: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-79045 (no input from JetBrains folks yet)
